# Knockout binding with resets jquery bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Given the following code:

```
<body data-bind="with: localization">
    <button id="btnLogin">Login</button>
</body>
```

And the following javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
        console.log('Clicked');
    });

    ko.applyBindings(MainView);
});
```

My console is empty if i click on the button

If I change the markup to this:

```
<body data-bind="">
    <button id="btnLogin">Login</button>
</body>
```

I get "clicked" in my console when testing.

How can I get my events to work properly?

Comment: Hmm, first scenario [seems to work](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CGIld) for me, logging "Clicked" to the console. What are you doing differently?

Comment: What happens if you do the Knockout bindings first and the jQuery binding second? Also, what browser(s) are you having the problem with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternate way to approach your problem, using Knockout to handle clicks:

```html
<body data-bind="with: localization, click: activate">
    <button id="btnLogin">Login</button>
</body>
```

And define the `activate` function on your ViewModel:

```
var Vm = function() {
    this.activate = function() { 
        console.log('view model activated, possibly through click'); 
    };
}
```

This allows you to re-use the `activate` logic elsewhere.

Comment: It's one way of solving it, and I'll probably use the click binding, but I'd still like to know how to stop KO.with to crash my jquery event bindings. For now I'm going to simply not use KO.with tho.